# IONIC Angular8 Application Production Build Generate Error

Tags: jquery, ionic4, angular8

My application is built using Ionic4 and Angular 8. It creates a service for `alertcontroller` and `toastcontroller` and both are used by call constructor and its applied on *Firebase* configuration, but when I build the following error shows up.

Does anyone know the source?

```
ERROR: Can't resolve all parameters for GeneralFunctionService in 
    /home/dhwani/IONIC/demo/src/app/service/general-function.service.ts:
    ([object Object], [object Object], ?).
```

GeneralFunctionService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { ToastController, AlertController, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) 
export class GeneralFunctionService { 
 params: any;

 constructor(
  public alertCtrl: AlertController, 
  public toastCtrl: ToastController, 
  params: string 
 ) {
 // …
```

Comment: Error is : 
ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for GeneralFunctionService in /home/dhwani/IONIC/demo/src/app/service/general-function.service.ts: ([object Object], [object Object], ?).

Comment: Can you show your GeneralFunctionService? It seems that the third parameter you give it is wrong.

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController, AlertController, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GeneralFunctionService {
  params: any;

  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    params: string
  ) {
    this.params = JSON.parse(params);
    if (this.params.func == 'showErrorMsg') {
      this.showErrorMsg(this.toastCtrl, this.params.msg)
    } else if (this.params.func == 'showAlertError') {
      this.showAlertError()
    }

  }

Comment: async showErrorMsg(toastCtrl, msg) {
    let toast = await toastCtrl.create({
      message: msg,
      duration: 2000,
      position: 'top'
    });
    await toast.present();
    window.location.reload();
  }
  async showAlertError() {

    let alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({

      message: 'Login Sucessful',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'OK',
          handler: () => {
            window.location.reload();
          }
        },
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();

  }
}

Comment: You can't give a parameter to the constructor like that "`params`". What are you trying to accomplish? Where does `this.params.func` come from?

Comment: firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)
        .then(
          res => {
            new GeneralFunctionService(this.alertctrl, this.toastctrl, JSON.stringify({ msg: res, func: 'showAlertError' }))
            this.navCtrl.navigateForward('Welcome');
            this.loginForm.reset();
          },
          err => {
            new GeneralFunctionService(this.alertctrl, this.toastctrl, JSON.stringify({ msg: err.message, func: 'showErrorMsg' }))
            this.loginForm.reset();
          }

        )

Comment: In the future, please add your code to your question instead of commenting it. That makes it easier to read.

Comment: Ok but for now can you help me in this code?

Comment: I posted an answer look below..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send the function as a parameter in a service. If you really want to do this with an if statement you should do that within the component.

So you can keep your service nice and clean like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ToastController,AlertController,NavController} from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class GeneralFunctionService {
    constructor(
        public alertCtrl: AlertController,
        public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    ) {}

    async showErrorMsg(toastCtrl, msg) {
        let toast = await toastCtrl.create({
            message: msg,
            duration: 2000,
            position: 'top'
        });
        await toast.present();

        window.location.reload();
    }

    async showAlertError() {
        let alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
            message: 'Login Sucessful',
            buttons: [{
                text: 'OK',
                handler: () => {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }, ]
        });
        await alert.present();
    }
}
```

Then in your component you should import the service and use it.

```
contructor(generalFunctionServ: GeneralFunctionService) {}

showMessage(param){
   if (param === 'showErrorMsg') { 
    this.generalFuncServ.showErrorMsg();
   } else if (param === 'showAlertError') { 
    this.generalFuncServ.showAlertError();
   }
}
```

I'm not sure where you get your param from so that part is up to you.